# ¿Cómo envíar una variable desde el controlador a la vista que se envía por e-mail?

Tags: laravel

Recibo los datos del formulario en el controlador, y requiero que la información del `$request->code` (un código que se genera aleatoriamente) lo pueda agregar al enlace que envío por correo al cliente, para que pueda accesar a su factura en línea, pero no tengo idea como hacerlo.

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    // Recibo el $request

    //Luego hago el envío del e-mail, pero necesito que en el archivo del correo se pueda agregar el valor de `$request['code']`

    $subject = "Factura de compra";
    $for = "cliente@gmail.com";
    Mail::send('mails/invoice',$request->all(), function($msj) use($subject,$for){
        $msj->from("web@gmail.com","Empresa");
        $msj->subject($subject);
        $msj->to($for);
    });

    // Luego verifico que sea el administrador y envío la consulta a la vista

    $user = User::find($id);

    if ($user->user_type == 'Admin')
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::groupBy('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);

        return view('invoices.index', compact('invoices'));
    }
```

Mi archivo del correo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="{{ url('http://www.miweb.com/web/invoice/') }}"> // requiero que sea {{ url('http://www.miweb.com/web/invoice/CODIGO') }}
            Ver factura y pagar.
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No termino de entender el problema, es decir en el mismo método donde tienes acceso al request esta código que envia el email, entonces ¿cuál es el problema para acceder al valor deseado del request?

Comment: Sí hago esto `{{ url('http://www.miweb.com/web/invoice/'.$request->code) }}` me dice que $request no está definido, esto está en el archivo que está en la siguienet ruta `resources/mails/invoice`

Comment: Posiblemente esté definida directamente como $code. Algo así funciona? `<a href="{{ url('http://www.miweb.com/web/invoice/'.$code') }}">`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, con `.code` funcionó. Eso porque? que no requiere el `$request`?

Comment: Joseph, realmente no lo sé. Se me ocurrió por como se le pasan datos a una vista, por ejemplo si en el request tienes un campo `code` y haces esto `view('welcome', $request->all())` sería equivalente a  `view('welcome', ['code' => $request->code, ...])`, y en cualquiera de los dos, en la vista accederías directamente a `$code`. Si averiguo como funciona la facade Mail escribiré una respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, quizás está asociaciado a esa explicación. Clave => Valor